# Android write to internal storage issue

Tags: java, android, storage

I've got an issue with writing to internal storage. I have read a lot of tutorials, but everywhere is this: `FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` 
But it says that **openFileOutput** is not a method.

Comment: In what class do you call this method?

Comment: openFileOutput is a method of Context class, Activity is a subclass of Context http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: You need instance of Context class, something like: `getContext().openfileOutput()`

Comment: Thank you. You can post it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openFileOutput` is a method of `Context` class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String,%20int)

`Activity` is a subclass of `Context`.
So if you are trying to call this method in `Activity`, it should be supported. 
If you trying to call it in some custom class, you should pass to it some instance of `Context` class or subclass (for example `Activity` instance)